# Insert foreign key value

Tags: php, symfony

I have two entities Project and Task. Task`s project_id value is mapped with project`s id.Every time creating a new task for a specific project, the project_id in the Task table should be set. Is there another way of doing this except using the hidden input field form?

createAction of TaskController

```
  public function createAction(Request $request)
  {
    $entity = new Tasks();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tasks_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('TestBundle:Tasks:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Every time you create a new task, you should add a reference to the project too.

Comment: if you use $task->setProject($project) it will be set automatically,

Comment: @Motammem can u please check the question again. I have updated it with the code. Where should i add that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get project that you want to assign tasks to it.
For example you can send it via `Request $request` then use it to query for `Project Object` then assign task to this object.

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
  {
    $entity = new Tasks();

    // doctrine entity manager
    $em = this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    // get project_id from query string
    $project_id = $request->get('project_id');

    // query database for project object
    $project = $em->getRepository("TestBundle:Project")->find($project_id);

    // assign task to project object
    $entity->setProject($project);

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tasks_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('TestBundle:Tasks:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Also  `newAction()` is better place to do this.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, call `setProject($project)` method in the controller action where you process the form

Comment: i have updated my question.Can u tell me where should i add that?

Comment: @Raj See Motammem's answer